# What is "brol"?

Tags: vocabulaire

I was reading a book and saw a character say "C'est quoi ce brol ?" I couldn't find the word in any dictionary. I do wish there was a decent Urban Dictionary for French, but there isn't. What does this word mean and why isn't it in dictionaries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Brol" is a belgicism. The general meaning is some kind of messy situation. See here: https://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/francais-definition/brol

For example, entering the room of your kids, you could probably more than often ask:

> C'est quoi ce brol ?

This is probably the meaning in your example

I've heard it quite often used also to describe an unidentified thing. Kinda as a synonym for "truc" or "machin". You could then ask the same question about let's say a mysterious email you received or a strange object on a colleague's desk, or some piece of contemporary art...

All my examples are real life ones, I use them on a regular basis.

Note this would only be understood by Belgian French speakers and is very familiar, while being slightly pejorative, so you may not be able to use it a lot yourself :-)

Comment: Also https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brol Without knowing the word, I would have understood it as a variant of *bordel* which is used at least in France with the very same meaning (*désordre, truc*). *Brol* etymology seems unclear, but *bordel* is not in the Wiktionary list.

Comment: To show how much this word is common in Belgium, it is often said that in private, Belgium's prince Charles (regent from 1945 to 1950 during a major institutional crisis) used to boast jokingly "j'ai sauvé le brol" (the "brol" being nothing less than the monarchy).

Comment: I tried reverso, what the hell? Thank you...dunno why it doesn't come up for me... Ohhhh, it's in the dictionary but not the French-English dictionary.